# How to access URL parameters in spring boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

My request is like below :-

```
http://example.com:8984/service/response?q=bags&source=desktop.search&city.data=mumbai|delhi
```

How can i access these values from the url such that i get the below map :-

```
{
q => bags,
source => desktop.search,
city.data => [mumbai, delhi]
}
```

i have written the below program :-

```
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class serviceController {

    @RequestMapping("/service/response")

    String getSearchString(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        return "SearchString ---- "+params;
    }
}
```

It is working fine when i giving only 1 parameter in city.data=mumbai
But getting below error when i am giving city.data=mumbai|delhi

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

Please suggest the correct way ?
thanks in advance

Comment: because `city.data` is an array, you can try to change the type of parameter to `Map<String, String[]>` then use `city.data=mumbai&city.data=delhi` to send them

Comment: Actually the request type pattern is fixed. I can't get this changed. I want to know this for organisation point of view. Please suggest me how to access the parameters in city.data=mumbai|delhi type.

Comment: You haven't added the error message that you get.

Comment: I am adding the error in the question posted. please check.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to send the params in a different way, but if you need a pipeline character you should replace it with the code `%7C`. Consequently, if you want to add `city.data=mumbai|delhi` as a param you should replace it for `city.data=mumbai%7Cdelhi`.

After that, you can parse the param in that field using the String methods.

Comment: Actually the request is coming from a different property and they are sending it with pipe only. I can't ask them to replace it with %7C. Please tell how can i access with pipe only ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a try like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestParam Map<String,String> param) {
    String[] city = org.springframework.util.StringUtils.split(param.get("city.data"), "|");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(city));
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

If you only have several parameters,you can also have a try like this.But the request url should be changed like this. ***test2?q=bags&source=desktop.search&city.data=mumbai&city.data=delhi***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test2")
@ResponseBody
public void test2(String q, String source, @RequestParam(value = "city.data") String[] city) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(city));
    System.out.println(source);
    System.out.println(q);
}
```